# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following ajax call which keeps giving the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token C" ,output of "sync.py: is
a  valid JSON format as shown below....what am I missing here?looked at other posts and am pretty much covering the suggestions listed..how to fix this error?please suggest

```
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",//note the contentType definition
                url: "scripts/sync.py",
                data: JSON.stringify(data_cp),
                //data: data_cp,
                error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log("cherypick fail");
                    console.log(response);      
                    console.log(response['returnArray']);
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError); 
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("cherypick sucess");
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response['returnArray']);                       
                }
            });
```

Error:-

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
```

OUTPUT OF sync.py which is valid JSON format

```
Content-Type: application/json


{"message": "The Command Completed Successfully", "returnArray": {"faillist": [], "picklist": ["1258565", "1279604"]}, "success": "true"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are returning `Content-Type: application/json` in the response body, and it should be a HTTP header.

You will get the same error if you do:

```
JSON.parse('Content-Type: application/json {"message": "The Command Completed Successfully", "returnArray": {"faillist": [], "picklist": ["1258565", "1279604"]}, "success": "true"}');
//SyntaxError: Unexpected token C
```

You should change your `sync.py` script to return only the JSON in the response body. That is:

```
{"message": "The Command Completed Successfully", "returnArray": {"faillist": [], "picklist": ["1258565", "1279604"]}, "success": "true"}
```

Comment: @matis - sorry ,i did not quite get it,how to fix this error?